# How to calculate coset intersection in gap

Tags: group-theory, gap

Given a finite group $G$ and two of its subgroups $S_1,S_2$,
I'd like to calculate the intersection of the cosets of $S_1$ and $S_2$.

This works but it's taking too long as the group size gets larger :

G:=(group);

S1:=Subgroup(G,...);Cosets1:=RightCosets(G,S1);

S2:=Subgroup(G,...);Cosets2:=RightCosets(G,S2);

R:=List(Cosets1,x->List(Cosets2,y->Size(Intersection(x,y))));

Are there faster ways to do this.

If it simplifies the problem, instead of the actual size of the intersection
I can also use a binary indicator whether the two cosets intersect or not.

Comment: @ahulpke : $G$ is defined abstractly as a quotient of a free group. the subgroups are generated by a subset of the generators of $G$. Since I know $G$ is finite, I turn it into a permutation group using IsomorphismPermGroup; that speeded things up considerably; but now I need another boost in speed for larger groups (>100K elements).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no special routine for the intersection of cosets - it computes elements lists and intersects these. Thus the inefficiency when working in larger groups.
In general, in GAP, working with transversals instead of cosets is faster, and the command `PositionCanonical` finds the transversal position corresponding to a given element.

The intersection of cosets of subgroups $S$, respectively $T$, is a coset of $S\cap T$ ([Intersection of cosets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/338650/intersection-of-cosets)). To find which cosets of $T$ a coset $Sx$ intersects, it is thus sufficient to split $Sx$ into cosets of $S\cap T$ (representatives are $cx$ where $c$ runs through a transversal of $S\cap T$ in $S$), and for each such coset $(S\cap T) cx$ find the coset of $T$ in which the representative $cx$ lies.

You can do so in GAP as follows (example, but this should work quickly for much larger sizes):

```
gap> G:=SymmetricGroup(6);;
gap> S:=Stabilizer(G,[1,2],OnSets);;T:=Stabilizer(G,[1,2,3],OnSets);;
gap> Ttrans:=RightTransversal(G,T);
RightTransversal(Sym( [ 1 .. 6 ] ),Group([ (4,5,6), (4,5), (1,2,3), (1,2) ]))
gap> ST:=Intersection(S,T);;
gap> ST:=Intersection(S,T);
Group([ (5,6), (4,5,6), (1,2)(5,6) ])
gap> STt:=RightTransversal(S,ST);
RightTransversal(Group([ (3,4,5,6), (3,4), (1,2) ]),Group(
[ (5,6), (4,5,6), (1,2)(5,6) ]))
gap> x:=(2,4,5);; # whatever element you want
gap> List(STt,c->PositionCanonical(Ttrans,c*x));
[ 5, 9, 8, 2 ]
```

So the coset $Sx$ intersects the cosets of $T$ with representatives in Positions 2,5,9,8. A brute-force check (not recommended in general) for this is:

```
gap> Filtered([1..Length(Ttrans)],y->Length(Intersection(S*x,T*Ttrans[y]))>0);
[ 2, 5, 8, 9 ]
```

(This approach assumes that the group is given as a permutation group (or a PCGroup). And - unavoidably - this becomes more expensive if the indices $[S:S\cap T]$ or $[G:T]$ become larger. But for example I tried itin $M_{24}$ (order ~$2\cdot 10^8$), it just took seconds. )

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I'm seeing considerable speedup already (>10x). Your solution has the added advantage of allowing the description of "R" as a sparse matrix (which it is); so there should be even more efficiency still.